# Do users of F-16s need the USA's permission to use them in attack roles?

Tags: united-states, military, turkey, pakistan, weapons

- [Document reveals official US position on F-16s](https://www.dawn.com/news/1522014)

Are users of [F-16 fighter planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dynamics_F-16_Fighting_Falcon) obliged to take the USA's permission to use them in attack roles?

I am especially curious about Turkey and Pakistan.

**P.S.** Someone mentioned Israel. In my opinion, US-Israel relations are special, and I’m primarily interested in other countries that don’t have such a close relationship.

Comment: It depends on what the word "need" means. "Legally necessary"? No. "Politically and diplomatically necessary to ensure their ability to get spare parts for the planes, or buy new ones in the future"? Whole different question.

Comment: @DanScally, I removed the word *need*.

Answer (score 4):

Legally, no. They have purchased a piece of hardware and they are responsible for how it is used. Even if it were written into the arms sale, a subsequent government could break that contract.

Practically, modern weapon systems contain a real lot of complicated software. Millions of lines of code. Can they be really sure that the US has not buried a "kill switch" in there? Rumors of that float around, but they're mostly just [rumors](https://www.wired.com/2008/05/kill-switch-urb/). Finding proof would really hurt future export prospects of that arms industry.

Comment: https://www.dawn.com/news/1522014    --- this article says otherwise.

Comment: Legally? Of course not. There is such a thing as sovereign immunity. But modern weaponry is more formula 1 race-car than hummer. These things spend more time being serviced than used. They need a continuous flow of parts and maintenance specialists from the provider.

Comment: @user366312, that's a matter affecting future sales, not their right to defend themselves.

Comment: @user189035, consider Iranian Tomcats (a few supposedly mission-capable decades after the revolution) and North Korean MD 500.

Comment: @user189035 Sovereign Immunity refers to immunity to suit from citizens of the sovereign, not outside action, so I don't think that's the right term.  On the other hand, I don't think there's an equivalent concept in international law because international law isn't enforced by one sovereign entity.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian: from wiki [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_immunity]: "Sovereign immunity, or crown immunity, is a legal doctrine whereby a sovereign or state cannot commit a legal wrong and is immune from civil suit or criminal prosecution[...]"

Comment: @o.m. Iranian tomcat/phoenix: the iranian could not have done it without support from Israel [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%27s_role_in_the_Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_war#Covert_arms_deal]. MD500. This is essentially a civilian chopper. That's a different matter. These are not designed to be inoperative without seller's support (no private buyer would accept that).

Answer (score 3):

No. Israel would be exhibit A in that category.

In 1981, Israel conducted [Operation Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Opera) using F-16 fighters to attack and destroy a nuclear reactor (being built by France) in Iraq. The US was not a party to it, nor did they publicly approve.

In 2007 [Operation Outside the Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Outside_the_Box) used F-15 and F-16 fighters to destroy a nuclear reactor being constructed in Syria. [The US was reluctant to get involved in any air strikes, but did not interfere with Israel doing it](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2012/09/17/the-silent-strike)

> Bush probably did not relish further military action and feared a repeat of the intelligence debacle in Iraq, but he seems to have understood Olmert’s position. At no point did Bush suggest that the U.S. would block Israeli action. “Olmert said he did not ask Bush for a green light, but Bush did not give Olmert a red light,” an Israeli general told me. “Olmert saw it as green.”

The US was kept informed, however

> On September 1st, Turbowicz told the White House that preparations were almost complete. Israel informed one other country’s intelligence service before the strike—Britain’s MI6—but did not share the exact timing of the attack with either country.

The catch for any country defying the US too far would be in the US simply cutting support off. Airplanes need to be maintained, and if you can't source parts then your fighters are basically giant hunks of metal after they break down.

Comment: Israel is an outlier. I wrote: *I am* ***especially*** *curious about Turkey and Pakistan.*

Comment: They are somewhat, but not entirely. If Israel has wiggle room, those countries do as well. It might not be to the same extent, but it's there.

Comment: @user366312 You seem to already have an answer. Self-answering is encouraged here. Then others can comment on it and the hundreds of examples.

Comment: Case in point, Iran's F-14 fleet. Cut off from most parts sources, they are pretty much museum pieces.